# Which team has the longest time not winning the top flight league championship?

Tags: football, trivia, records

September 6, 2017, marks 10,000 days since [Liverpool FC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liverpool_F.C.) last won the English league title. Of course, I know they're not the record-holders, but I'd like to know who are?

Which team has gone the longest time without winning the top-flight league championship? Given that the team has won at least 1 title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Preston North End](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preston_North_End_F.C.) last won the [English Football League in **18**90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1889%E2%80%9390_Football_League), 127 years ago.